# Orleans grains similar to NServiceBus Sagas?

Tags: nservicebus, distributed-computing, orleans

I Just watched the video of how Orleans was used to build Halo 4's Distributed cloud services

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-641

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you read through both sets of documentation and see which features most closely match your requirements:

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas-in-nservicebus

https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

After going through Richard's course in the Pluralsight, I think that both overlap in functionalities. In my understanding, the grains are virtual, single threaded and live in a distributed environment like cloud.